# How to save String object into an ArrayList and also remove the HashMap inside of this ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have an ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, and I want to remove `status_id=X` and only keep `status_name=X` and save into ArrayList. How can I do it?

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> statusList = [{status_id=1, status_name=iceCream}, {status_id=2, status_name=cake (chocolate)}]
```

The expected result should print:

```
[status_name=iceCream, status_name=cake(chocolate)]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the ArrayList code you have shown is an actual java code or its a pseudocode? I am confused because we have `HashMap` and the key and value of the Map is String, but here you have fields `status_id` and `status_name`.

Comment: What does `and also remove the HashMap inside of this ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` mean? Show the `statusList` of the execution result.

Comment: @Deepak Patankar, It was made by the print result from database by java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you need a list of `Map.Entry` where the key is mapped to `status_name`. If you are on Java 8+ version, you can flatten the hashmap and apply a filter on it.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> statusNames = statusList.stream()
        .flatMap(hashMap -> hashMap.entrySet().stream())
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("status_name"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you are on the pre-java 7 version. you need to iterate over element HashMap and add the required `Map.Entry` to a separate list.

```
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> statusNames = new ArrayList();

for (Map<String, String> tempMap : statusList) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : tempMap.entrySet()) {
        if(entrySet.getKey().equals("status_name"))
            statusNames.add(entrySet);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Java8 and this worked well!! Thank you Govinda Sakhare for the help!!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code-

```
          public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> statusList = new ArrayList();
            Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
            map1.put("status_id","1");
            map1.put("status_name","ice_cream");
    
            Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
            map2.put("status_id","2");
            map2.put("status_name","cake (chocolate)");
    
            statusList.add(map1);
            statusList.add(map2);
    
            System.out.print(statusList);
    
            List<String> list1 =  statusList.stream().map(x -> x.get("status_name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.print(list1);
          }
```

Comment: Thank you Ashley for approving. :)